# Catch-22 in the bundle ID of a new target

Tags: xcode, appstore-approval

Hullo,

while trying to submit a new target of a project to the AppStore I am caught in a no exit solution. In particular I receive error:
"... does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application"; if, following the instructions to solve this problem from Apple I set SkipInstall to YES, the target end up in the wrong folder when archived and I get a mismatch error between the Bundle IDs on iTunes Connect and Xcode.
So I am really stuck at this.
Thanks in advance for your answers,

Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: the suggestion to set Skip install to YES was misleading: the problem was actually in the old bundle coexisting  with the new one in the schema.